# If $\int f(x) \sin{x} \cos{x}\,\mathrm dx = \frac {1}{2(b^2 - a^2)} \log f(x) +c $. Find $f(x)$

Tags: derivatives

> **Problem**: If $\int f(x) \sin{x}  \cos{x}\,\mathrm  dx = \frac {1}{2(b^2 - a^2)} \log f(x) +c $. Find $f(x)$
>
> **Solution**: $\int f(x) \sin{x}  \cos{x}\,\mathrm  dx = \frac {1}{2(b^2 - a^2)} \log f(x) +c $
>
> Differenting both sides,we get
>
> $ f(x) \sin{x}  \cos{x} = \frac {f'(x)}{2(b^2 - a^2)f(x)}  $

Am I doing right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a good start. For simplicity write $y$ for $f(x)$. We can rewrite the result you got as 
$$\frac{y'}{y^2}=2(b^2-a^2)\sin x\cos x.$$
Integrate both sides. It may be handy to note that $2\sin x\cos x=\sin(2x)$. Or not, since it is clear that $2\sin x\cos x$ is the derivative of $\sin^2 x$.

Comment: Thanks.Now it becomes a question of differential equation

Comment: @rst A really simple differential equation...

Comment: Yes, but it is a separable DE, so it comes down to a couple of integrals both of which are familiar to you.

Answer (score 5):

Yes and to complete: we have

$$\int f'(x)(f(x))^{-2}\;dx=C\int\sin(2x)\;dx$$
where $C=b^2-a^2$ so 
$$-\frac{1}{f(x)}=-\frac{C}{2}\cos(2x)+C'$$
and you can take $f(x)$ from it.